# Executing Oracle Explain Plan in C#

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g

Normally, executing an "explain plan" for an sql statement results in records inserted into plan_table. This works fine for me when executed via TOAD. My requirement is to execute this via my c# application (Oracle.DataAccess.Client lib). Unfortunately, the same statement that worked on TOAD is not resulting in any records inserted into plan_table when executed in C#.

The peculiar thing is that I know for sure the plan_id sequence is being consumed when executed in C# although no records are inserted into the table. I can confirm this by executing a new explain plan in TOAD and notice that plan_id sequence has skipped based on the number of attempts i made via C#. [Notice how it went from 44 to 50.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpKCu.jpg)

The reason I need explain plan specifically is that I want to fetch the list of tables and columns involved in a given query BEFORE execution. I considered syntax parsing but it felt like reinventing the wheel given that plan_table records contained exactly the data I wanted.

For all intents and purposes, the same user is logged on TOAD and C# so I am not suspecting limited privileges. I tried with and without committing. I have also tried putting the explain plan in a stored procedure and calling that in C# with the same results. (works as expected on TOAD, but no records inserted on C#). For it to work in a stored procedure, I had to make it EXECUTE IMMEDIATE.

```
myoracon.Open();
OracleCommand myoracom = myoracon.CreateCommand();
myoracom = new OracleCommand("explain plan set statement_id = 'xd' for select * from employee", myoracon);
OracleTransaction trx;
trx = myoracom.Connection.BeginTransaction();
myoracom.Transaction = trx;
myoracom.ExecuteNonQuery();
trx.Commit();
myoracon.Close();
```

So, after all this,  my question is the following: Why is explain plan in C# not resulting in records inserted into plan_table and what can I do to get it to work?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you control the table : `TOAD_PLAN_TABLE` in which user you run the script on **C#**

if it does not exists create it manuelly under your c# user :

```
CREATE TABLE **your_user**.TOAD_PLAN_TABLE
(
  STATEMENT_ID       VARCHAR2(30 BYTE),
  PLAN_ID            NUMBER,
  TIMESTAMP          DATE,
  REMARKS            VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
  OPERATION          VARCHAR2(30 BYTE),
  OPTIONS            VARCHAR2(255 BYTE),
  OBJECT_NODE        VARCHAR2(128 BYTE),
  OBJECT_OWNER       VARCHAR2(30 BYTE),
  OBJECT_NAME        VARCHAR2(30 BYTE),
  OBJECT_ALIAS       VARCHAR2(65 BYTE),
  OBJECT_INSTANCE    INTEGER,
  OBJECT_TYPE        VARCHAR2(30 BYTE),
  OPTIMIZER          VARCHAR2(255 BYTE),
  SEARCH_COLUMNS     NUMBER,
  ID                 INTEGER,
  PARENT_ID          INTEGER,
  DEPTH              INTEGER,
  POSITION           INTEGER,
  COST               INTEGER,
  CARDINALITY        INTEGER,
  BYTES              INTEGER,
  OTHER_TAG          VARCHAR2(255 BYTE),
  PARTITION_START    VARCHAR2(255 BYTE),
  PARTITION_STOP     VARCHAR2(255 BYTE),
  PARTITION_ID       INTEGER,
  OTHER              LONG,
  DISTRIBUTION       VARCHAR2(30 BYTE),
  CPU_COST           INTEGER,
  IO_COST            INTEGER,
  TEMP_SPACE         INTEGER,
  ACCESS_PREDICATES  VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
  FILTER_PREDICATES  VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
  PROJECTION         VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
  TIME               INTEGER,
  QBLOCK_NAME        VARCHAR2(30 BYTE),
  OTHER_XML          CLOB
)
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot. I can't believe it was that simple! I compared your above creation script to the actual description of my environment's plan_table. The position of OTHER_XML column differed (very minor detail), but I just tested it and it worked. I guess the issue was that PLAN_TABLE needs to be defined in my schema. Thanks again! :D

Answer (score 0):

The explain plan is written in specific table `PLAN_TABLE`. You need to Select it to see the exact plan. Check [**Using EXPLAIN PLAN**](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96533/ex_plan.htm#21502)

```
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR
SELECT last_name FROM employees;
```

> This explains the plan into the PLAN_TABLE table. You can then select
>   the execution plan from PLAN_TABLE. This is useful if you do not have
>   any other plans in PLAN_TABLE, or if you only want to look at the last
>   statement.

**In your case you will select it with your specific ID which you set.**

So you need another connection to db:

```
using(OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(oradb))
{
    conn.Open();
    OracleCommand cmd= conn.CreateCommand();
    cmd.Connection = conn;

    cmd.CommandText = @"Select * FROM Plan_Table Where ID=@ID";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", idWhichYouSpecify);

    DataTable tbl = new DataTable();

    using(OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd))
    {
        da.Fill(tbl);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I failed to mention that this is still a Proof of Concept and I just wanted to check if explain plan would execute successfully. Currently, I am looking up plan_table manually via TOAD to check if the explain plan worked as expected when executed in C#.

Comment: @Mr.Wright you can load the information from plan_table in C# too like I wrote.